# Why isn't the value inserted in the database using following code?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to submit a form and insert a value in a table Status. But it's not working. What's wrong in it?

The table name is "Status" and the last column name is "Votes", where I want to insert the value. I think the query is not running as it isn't echoing "Done".

Here's the code:

```
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
$ids=$idsorted[$x];
$sts=$stsorted[$x];
$profilenamearray=array();
$idnamequery="SELECT Name FROM signup WHERE Email='$ids'";
$idnamequeryrun=mysqli_query($mysqls, $idnamequery);
$rowidname=mysqli_fetch_assoc($idnamequeryrun);
$profilenamearray[]=$rowidname["Name"];
  ?>
          <h4 style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #008080; margin: 0px;"> 

          <?php echo $profilenamearray[0];

          ?> </h4>
          <p class="updates"><?php echo $sts; 

          $votequeryrun="";
          if (isset($_REQUEST['submitbutton']))
          {
                $votecheck="SELECT Votes FROM status WHERE statusupdate='$sts'";
                $votecheckrun=mysqli_query($mysqls, $votecheck);
                $rowvote=mysqli_fetch_assoc($votecheckrun);
                $nofvotes=$rowvote["Votes"];
                $nofvotesN=$nofvotes+1;
                echo $nofvotesN;
                    $votequery="INSERT INTO status(Votes) VALUES('$nofvotesN') WHERE statusupdate='$sts'";
                    $votequeryrun=mysqli_query($mysqls, $votequery);
                    if($votequeryrun)
                    {
                        echo "done";
                        header("Location: welcomehome.php");
                    }
            }

          ?></p>
  <form name="votes" method="post" action="">
         <input type="submit" name="submitbutton">Vote</input>
        </form>


          <hr>
          <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or anything at all? Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: `Where` condition in `INSERT` query???

Comment: @Safty, thanks that seems the problem. Let me try.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe want to use UPDATE if you are using the WHERE clause.
INSERT adds a new line, so there is no point of using a where clause.

Comment: UPDATE status SET Votes='$nofvotesN' WHERE statusupdate='$sts'